# fprintd and fingerpring authentication does not work after enrolling my fingerprints on Asus Zenbook UM431DA-AM003

Tags: 20.04, asus, authentication, fingerprint-reader

I bought recently Asus Zenbook UM431DA-AM003 and installed Ubuntu 20.04 (Focal). I was trying to enroll my fingers using swipe method (not touch) and it worked fine:

```
~$ fprintd-enroll
Using device /net/reactivated/Fprint/Device/0
Enrolling right-index-finger finger.
Enroll result: enroll-stage-passed
Enroll result: enroll-stage-passed
Enroll result: enroll-stage-passed
Enroll result: enroll-stage-passed
Enroll result: enroll-completed
```

GUI method worked, too.

But when I try `frpintd-verify` and verified my right index finger I get this message:

```
Verify result: verify-no-match (done)
```

Certainly, auth does not work.

I checked if my device is supported or not in [supported list](https://fprint.freedesktop.org/supported-devices.html). It is supported:

```
~$ lsusb 
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 005: ID 04f3:0903 Elan Microelectronics Corp. 
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 8087:0a2b Intel Corp. USB2.0 Hub
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 13d3:56dd IMC Networks 
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 05e3:0608 Genesys Logic, Inc. Hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

**Bus 003 Device 005: ID 04f3:0903 Elan Microelectronics Corp.**

I have no idea how to fix this problem and use my finger as authentication method.

Answer (score 1):

You mentioned enrolling fingers (plural). Try running `fprintd-list` and seeing which finger is the first listed. Try running `printd-verify` and testing that finger. Haven't discovered why but on my machine (Synaptics touch reader) it will only properly verify the first print in the list. My current "solution" is to only have a single finger enrolled until I can track down the cause.

Comment: tried to remove all and keep only one new fingerprint, but doesn't work !